# Railsの開発環境でログが出力されなくなった

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsの開発環境でログが肥大化して開かなくなったたため、
よく調べずに手動でファイルを削除してしまいました。

development.logというファイルを手動で作成したのですが、
それ以降、ログが全く出力されなくなってしまいました。

デフォルトで出力される内容も、
コントローラにlogger.debugで書いたものもどちらもダメです。

どうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: rails の再起動は試しましたか?

Comment: 手動でファイルを作成したのであれば、Railsがそのファイルに対して書き込み権限があるか確認しましょう。

Comment: @masm 再起動で直りました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: @htbそれ以前の問題でした…ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

おそらく rails server は名前のなくなったファイルにログを書き続けています。

ファイルの削除とは、ディレクトリ（原義は名簿、ここではファイルの名簿)からファイル名とファイル本体の結びつきを消す(unlink)ことです。一度ファイルを開いてしまえば、開いた時のファイル名がなくなっても、関係なく読み書きが出来ます。実際Tempfileなどはopenしたらすぐunlinkすることも多いです。

以上の推測が正しければ、rails server を再スタートすれば、改めてログファイルを開く(開けて、書けるパーミッションは必要）ので、出力されるようになると思います。

なお、ログが肥大化している場合は、Rakeタスク log:clear を使ってサイズをゼロに出来ます。

Comment: rails serverの再起動で直りました。詳細な説明もありがとうございました！